BigQuery ML Support Request
BigQuery Error Support Request
Hello,
I am facing the following error message while working with BigQuery:
Error Message:
Function not found: PREDICT at [3:3]
Code:
SQL CODE
SELECT
*,
PREDICT(Kredi_Analizi.kmeans_model_germany,
STRUCT(Kredi_Notu, Kadin, Erkek, Yas, Kullanim_Hakki, Bakiye, Hesap_Sayisi, Kredi_Karti, Tahmini_Maas)) AS Almanya_Kume
FROM
bigqueryml-417120.Kredi_Analizi.KrediTablo
WHERE
Almanya = 1 AND Cikti = 1;
Issue:
According to the error message, the PREDICT function cannot be found.
Attempted Solutions:
I also tried the function name as ML.PREDICT.
I verified the correctness of the project ID, dataset name, and model name.
I confirmed that the BigQuery ML API is enabled for my project.
I checked that the model is in the "TRAINED" state.
Please assist me in resolving this error.
Thank youenter image description here

The correct function seems to be ML.PREDICT: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-predict#predict_an_outcome

The correct table value function is ML.PREDICT. Please follow the syntax in Google’s documentation.
Note that ML.PREDICT is not a scalar function, so it has to be used in a format like:
select * from ML.predict(model, table, struct())

